# VS 2010 Properties Page Fail to Show-COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used

Tags: visual-studio-2010, properties

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition, but now it won't show the project properties page. Instead an error message show up saying
***An error occurred trying to load the page.
COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.***

This error has plagued me for a long time. I tried almost everything (uninstall/reinstall/repair/uninstall addins, etc) except reinstall 
OS. 
Help me out. Thx a lot!

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you start the Visual Studio IDE in [safe mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx)?

Answer (score 33):

Finally I found out what had gone wrong. It's misbehaving addin - TestDriven.NET. 
But things could be different for you. But anyway, it's addins. 
The process to find this is that you Goto "Tools -> Options" dialog. Goto "Environment -> Add-ins/Macros Security" node. Uncheck "Allow add-in components to load". And then restart VS 2010 to see if the issue goes away. If it does, then it must be an addin in those folders specified. And next step is to enable addins to load, and remove the directories in the list one by one to identity which addin caused the issue. And at last, disable or simply remove/uninstall it.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the same problem for me. I removed several folders as per your answer.

Comment: If Visual Studio is being silly and won't let you remove the add-in folders, you can remove them manually from here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\AutomationOptions\LookInFolders

Comment: I have the exact same problem. TestDriven.Net seems to be the misbehaving for me too.

Comment: Note that this will prevent TestDriven.NET from executing any tests within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8):

Restarted VS 2010 SP1 solved my problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

in my case it was the latest update of VSCommands for VS2010...
A complete UnInstall/Re-Install of the VSCommands did the job :)

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me for some unknown reason and it turned out I had to disable source-control plugin (the default one that had been happily working for a long time):
`Tools -> Options -> Source control : set plug-in to "None"` and restart VS.

Comment: I had to do this and then my issue was fixed. I was able to turn it back on and the issue has not returned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in **Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Service pack 1**. I found that it was happening due to **GhostDoc Community**.

I upgraded **GhostDoc Community 4.9.x to 5.1.x and issue get resolved** in Visual Studio 2015 Service pack 1.

Comment: thank you, i was losing hope all these references to vs2010 - and you came through like a ray of sunshine - was ghostdoc for me too, vs2015.3

Comment: I am glad to hear that my answer is helpful to you.